# Why some picture was rotated is iOS device?

Tags: ios, macos, jpeg

It's very strange that the same picture display different on PC/Mac/iOS device.

This URL of a picture:
http://imgtest.meiliworks.com/pic/d/b3/0d/1a6157b2828bbcbfadb0d4d114b0_600_2400.jpg

it's 77x310 in safari on Mac OSX 10.7,
but it's 310x77 in safari on iPad!

if I download the picture and open it directly, it's become 310x77.

what's wrong with my picture?

Comment: Wow, closed with 5 downvotes, but it sure helped me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image contains an EXIF orientation tag with the value of 6 (rotated 90 degrees left). Not all image viewers handle this tag properly. For those that don't respect it, they'll display the image rotated 90 degrees right.